# Hot to get list of engines running?

Tags: apache

I need to block files in directory from being executed, i was recommended to set

```
php_flag engine off
```

Now i need go get list of other engines running and disable each of them.

Comment: Its not my machine, i know what i have on my machine but code that i am using needs to work elsewhere, and it has to be secure..

Comment: You need to change the configuration files of active vhosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking to secure a kind of a file upload directory from executing source codes.

**1) Security checks :**
You may first check whether this directive *php_flag engine off* is effectively taken into account by your server, putting a php file and calling it from your browser. As far as I remember, this directive works with Apache2 and above but not below.

Provided that you can activate additional php modules (mod_mime), I guess you could also complete your *.htaccess* file by 2 lines :

```
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5 .cgi .fcgi 
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5 .cgi .fcgi 
php_flag engine off
```

**2) "Running engines" :**
Your question is not clear to me and in any case, the answer depends on your OS and distro. On a debian, you'll show up information about Apache, Bind DNS, or Postfix smtp server and their port numbers like this :

```
netstat -tulpn
```

**3) AddHandler :**
But maybe you are looking for the file types handled by the server in a particular directory. For this, you have to check your *apache.conf* or *httpd.conf* file and find which types of files are handled in your conf file(s). Then you shall check for the *AddHandler* directives. To find those lines on a debian machine with apache2 installed from the standard packages into the default directories :

```
grep --color -Rn -e "handler" -e "type" /etc/apache2/*.conf
```